# Are ulimits inherited by the shell, by the user, or a combination?

Tags: unix, shell, ulimit, hp-server-automation

When a process spawns a subshell, how is the `ulimit` inherited?

Is it by user, by shell, or a combination?

Specifically, this was found in the context of HP Server Automation jobs failing on some managed AIX devices because of an interaction between the soft and hard `ulimits` in place. In short, the Agent (which runs as `root` and generates a subshell when processing commands from SA) was unable to process some jobs because its subshell was hitting a `ulimit`.

Increasing the `ulimit` solved the problem, but the question of how the `ulimit` is inherited, and whether the soft or hard (or both) limits need to be raised is left open.

What is the appropriate answer to this question? It may be AIX-specific, or it may be across Unix/Linux variants - whichever is better.

Comment: Nothing shell specific goes to ulimit. It is a resource limit, users exhaust it. By user, I mean userspace app/process which uses kernel and hardware limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The details of implementation vary across *nix platforms , but ulimit is initially set per user, with a default for all users that covers those who lack a specific setting.

In the specific case of AIX, these settings are in **/etc/security/limits**.  Linux uses the slightly-different name /etc/security/limits.conf to do the same job.  To be safe, do
`man ulimit` to find the answer for your particular OS.

Comment: so - there is no correlation to shell in use?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What "correlation" do you think might exist?

Comment: if the default shell is bash, for example, and you expect it to be ksh and you don't account for it, there are various environment variables which may (or may not) exist. Also, if it is an interactive session vs headless, some things are different. Hence the clarifying question.

Comment: ulimit does not have anything to do with the default shell, or whether the session is interactive vs. a cron job, etc.  If you need that kind of "correlation", you can implement it by putting a ulimit command in .bashrc that won't be executed by ksh, etc.

Comment: @warren On Linux, using the bash shell, ulimit is a shell builtin and the ulimits specified within one shell are inherited by processes (including subshells) that are spawned from that shell.  From the man page: "ulimit ... Provides control over the resources available to the shell and to processes started by it, on systems that allow such control."